# Cannot access value of session php

Tags: php

I am unable to access value of my Php Sessions, I have looked at other post on Stack tried using there solution, but cannot solve it, I first check if cookie is allowed, if cookie is allowed I get the cookie, but if it is not I create the session and access the session.

BUT I CANNOT ACCESS THE SESSION THAT WAS CREATED

my code..

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    if ($_COOKIE > 0) //check if cookie is enabled {

  //have created the cookie works well

  } else { //then if cookie not found, use session, I turned off my browser cookie accept to test and code session


 if(isset($_SESSION['shar]) 
  && 
  !empty($_SESSION[shar]) & 
 isset($_SESSION[language]) 
 && 
!empty 
($_SESSION['language']) 
 { //create session if not found
$_SESSION['Shar'] = 'news';
$_SESSION['language] = 'English';
  } else { //view session content
  var_dump($_SESSION);
   //I GET AN EMPTY ARRAY 
  }

  }
```

Comment: Call `session_start();` first without conditions. Or `isset` cookies.

Comment: Try to use isset($_COOKIE) instead of count($_COOKIE)

Comment: @get set still not working

Comment: Dont know what u mean without changing your post here @Shasha ... Spot fixing overall is a spotty error prone debugging technique. *Understand* what you are doing, better approach.

Comment: @almog works well the cookie checked accurately it's the session that is the issue

Comment: @Shasha `session_start()` must come *before any* output to the browser, including outputted errors.

Comment: @getset done the edits

Comment: Ok @getset done still the same error

Comment: `if ($_COOKIE > 0)` but its an array. Would you treat an array like this?

Comment: You are not simply understanding . Write this `if (isset($_COOKIE) && count($_COOKIE) > 0)`

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: @Dlk am not getting the array in vardump

Comment: maybe you should entirely rewrite your code. As it's displayed here, it lacks proper indentation, this could lead to some mistakes (forgotten ";", etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is a Cookie ?**

A cookie is often used to identify a user. A cookie is a small file that the server embeds on the user's computer. Each time the same computer requests a page with a browser, it will send the cookie too. With PHP, you can both create and retrieve cookie values.

```
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "John Doe";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); 
// 86400 = 1 day
```

> Note: The `setcookie()` function must appear BEFORE the  tag.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
```

The above example created a cookie named "user" with the value "John Doe". The cookie will expire after 30 days (86400 * 30). The "/" means that the cookie is available in entire website (otherwise, select the directory you prefer).

**Check if Cookies are Enabled**

The following example creates a small script that checks whether cookies are enabled. First, try to create a test cookie with the `setcookie()` function, then count the `$_COOKIE` array variable:

```
if(count($_COOKIE) > 0) {
    echo "Cookies are enabled.";
} else {
    echo "Cookies are disabled.";
}
```

**What is a PHP Session ?**

Session variables hold information about one single user, and are available to all pages in one application.

A session is started with the `session_start()` function.

Session variables are set with the PHP global variable: `$_SESSION`.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
$_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
echo "Session variables are set.";
```

> Note: The `session_start()` function must be the very first thing in
>   your document. Before any HTML tags.

**Get PHP Session Variable Values**

Notice that session variables are not passed individually to each new page, instead they are retrieved from the session we open at the beginning of each page (`session_start()`).

Also notice that all session variable values are stored in the global `$_SESSION` variable:

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

**Importand part**

You are checking for cookies but trying to get session values!
The code in question is a Collected code from there and there, I recommend you to read about php sessions and cookies and see some tutorials to write your own code.

See : https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php
See : https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php